# Cannot parse space-separated output of awk

Tags: bash, awk, array

If I understand correctly, the default separator for the output of `awk` is [space](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html).

However, the following script does not behave as I expect. I do not manage to parse the output of `awk` into an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "------ with input string from awk ------"
ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR=$(ls -l /dev | grep tty | awk '{print $3}')

read -r -a ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY <<< "$ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR"

echo "${#ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[@]}" # This says 1
echo "${ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[0]}" # "root", as expected
echo "${ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[1]}" # empty string, expected "root"
echo "${ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[2]}" # empty string, expected "root"


echo "------ with my manually created input string ------"
ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR="root root root" # only for testing

read -r -a ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY <<< "$ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR"

echo "${#ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[@]}" # 3, as expected
echo "${ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[0]}" # "root", as expected
echo "${ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[1]}" # "root", as expected
echo "${ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY[2]}" # "root", as expected
```

Why can't I parse the output of `awk` with `read` as I expected I could?

Comment: I don't know what your larger goal is, but I advise _not writing a shell script_. You're having problems with whitespace and you're attempting to use Bash arrays -- both of those are red flags that the problem you are trying to solve is too complicated for a shell script. If you have Bash, you have the option of using a better scripting language like Perl or Python.  (And conversely, if you _don't_ have access to anything but shell, you probably can't use Bash extensions.)

Comment: @zwol I am parsing the output of `xrandr` to get the names of connected output. Until recently I placed what I have directly in my `.bashrc`, now in a separate sh file. Why is it too complicated for bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's about **field** separator.

You need to define **record** separator to put each string in single one. Use `ORS` param:

```
ls -l /dev | grep tty | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; {print $3}'
```

Without it you output will:

```
root
root
root
etc...
```

And when you define `ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR` variable you **put only first** string of output in first element of array. Because of this you array will contain only one element and this is exactly what you are gets

Comment: I see. I got confused because `echo ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR` after the assignment does output all on a single line. This makes it look like it's a space-separated string, but it isn't?

Answer (score 4):

The default field separator for output is space. But the record separator is a new line. `ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR` contains a bunch of `root`s separated by newlines:

```
$ printf "%q\n" "$ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR"
$'root\nroot\nroot\n....
```

And `read` by default reads upto the first newline.

If you just want all the users in `ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY`, it might be simpler to do something like:

```
ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY=( $(stat -c '%U' /dev/*tty*) )
```

Comment: oh, I used `echo` instead of `printf`, and the `\n` seem to be replaced by a space in the output of my term!

Answer (score 3):

`read -a array` reads all the words from one record into `array`.

If you want to read all the words from the whole input, use a record separator that doesn't occur in the input, like with `-d ''` that uses the NUL character as the record separator, or `-d :` (as `:` cannot occur in a username).

```
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array < <(ls -Ll /dev | awk '/tty/{print $3}')
```

(here using `-L` so that for symlinks, the ownership of the devices as opposed to the symlink is returned).

Or use `readarray` for each **line** of the input to be stored in the array.

```
readarray -t array < <(ls -Ll /dev | awk '/tty/{print $3}')
```

Or you could use the split+glob operator:

```
set -o noglob # disable glob part
IFS=$'\n'     # split on newline
array=($(ls -Ll /dev | awk '/tty/{print $3}')) # invoke split+glob by leaving
                                               # the $(...) unquoted.
```

Note that the `tty` is looked for in the whole output of `ls -Ll`, so including user and group name, file name (and target of symlink if you omit the `-L`). If you want to consider only the filename, you could do

```
ls -Lld /dev/*tty* | awk '{print $3}'
```

instead.

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -s -A array +uid /dev/*tty*
```

(which would have the benefit of also working for user names containing blanks).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't quote the variable after `<<<`, the newlines will become the whitespace you expect and the result will be all on one line:

```
read -r -a ALL_TTY_OWNERS_ARRAY <<< $ALL_TTY_OWNERS_STR
```

Comment: That was a [bug, fixed in bash4.4](https://fossies.org/diffs/bash/4.4-beta_vs_4.4-rc1/CWRU/changelog-diff.html). bash4.4 now preserves the newlines like in other shells. `BASH_COMPAT=4.3` won't restore the old behaviour.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I was using 4.3.42.